# Symfony API doesn't return any response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, symfony

When attempting to connect the Symfony API with a React application, there is an issue where the API refuses to return any response. However, when accessing the API link directly, the response is returned correctly.

[ApiDirectURL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s6tf.png)

However, attempting to fetch this data through the React application does not return anything.

```
  const api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app-api/";
  const farmid = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
  
  async function getFarmInfo() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url + farmid + "/info",{
      cache: "no-store", 
      mode: "no-cors",
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }});
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    console.log(jsonData);
  }
```

[ServerResponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79QgK.png)

Not responding API Code

```
   #[Route('/info', name: 'info')]
    public function info(Request $request,EntityManagerInterface $em,$fishingfarmid): Response
    {

        $farm = $em->getRepository(FishingFarm::class)->findOneBy(["trueId" => $fishingfarmid]);
        $json = ["phone" => $farm->getPhone() , "regulation" => $farm->getRegulations() , "email" => $farm->getEmail() , "address" => $farm->getAddress()];
        return new JsonResponse($json);
    }
```

However, by accident, I discovered that if I use the var_dump(""); function somewhere, the response in the React code suddenly appears.

```
#[Route('/info', name: 'info')]
public function info(Request $request,EntityManagerInterface $em,$fishingfarmid): Response
{

    $farm = $em->getRepository(FishingFarm::class)->findOneBy(["trueId" => $fishingfarmid]);
    $json = ["phone" => $farm->getPhone() , "regulation" => $farm->getRegulations() , "email" => $farm->getEmail() , "address" => $farm->getAddress()];
    var_dump("");
    return new JsonResponse($json);
}
```

The result of the `var_dump`

[image: Response with var_dump()]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but it works after removing `mode: "no-cors"`.

```
 async function getFarmInfo() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url + farmid + "/info",{
      method: "GET",
     });
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    
    setFarmInfo( jsonData);
  }
```